# Inner join in php redbeans

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, redbean

I have following structure

```
USER
 user_id
 name

EVENT
 event_id
 user_id
 event_name
```

How can I write inner join in redbean?

```
SELECT * FROM event e join user u on u.user_id = e.user_id
```

also how can I change Primary key of table schema in redbeans

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP..

Comment: Can anybody help me ?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
SELECT u.user_ID, u.name, e.event_id, e.user_id, e.event_name
from user u
inner join event e
on u.user_id=e.user_id
```

as you can see. You **select all** the columns from table event. Of course by doing this, it will not include the columns from table user. Thus we will now include all the column you want to display one by one and of course with it's respective alias.

Comment: Thanks for you help mate .I know how to write queries .. what I want to know is how can I do it in redbeans way :)